# How do I perform 'WHERE' on groups of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table, which looks like:

```
+-----------+----------+
+ person_id + group_id +
+-----------+----------+
+    1      +    10    +
+    1      +    20    +
+    1      +    30    +
+    2      +    10    +
+    2      +    20    +
+    3      +    10    +
+-----------+----------+
```

I need a query such that only person_ids with groups 10 AND 20 AND 30 are returned (only person_id: 1). I am not sure how to do this, as from what I can see it would require me to group the rows by person_id and then select the rows which contain all group_ids.

I'm looking for something which will preserve the use of keys without resorting to string operations on `group_concat()` or such.

Comment: `WHERE group_id IN (10, 20, 30)`

Comment: @kirilloid, that will still return all the persons

Comment: I got your idea. AFAIK, there's only way to do that: use multiple JOINs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
select person_id from t
where group_id in (10, 20, 30)
group by person_id
having count(distinct group_id) = 3
```

Although efficient, using this solution the amount of values in the `in` will have to match the value you compare the count with.

And the just-for-fun solution, as you said, even with `group_concat` you can solve this :P

```
select person_id from t
where group_id in (10, 20, 30)
group by person_id
having group_concat(distinct group_id order by group_id) = '10,20,30'
```

Comment: Thanks :) I hope you're not talking about the `group_concat` stuff :P

Comment: ;-) distinct group_id is essential to zero-maintenance query.

Comment: Yeah, I'll skip the group_concat(). :-P But this is SO at its best. Spent 4 hours of friday trying to solve it. Ask the question on the way to work on the train and before I arrive at work, problem solved. And yes, I gave credit to SO. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Group and count hits:

```
select person_id
  from ATable
 where group_id IN (10, 20, 30)
 group by person_id
having count(*) = 3
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT person_id FROM... WHERE group_id IN(10,20,30) group by person_id
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: That will perform an OR on group_id

Comment: ah right sorry you want it only to get it where person_id = 1
well SELECT person_id FROM... WHERE person_id = 1 AND WHERE group_id IN(10,20,30)